# Is it okay to delete buildToolsVersion android studio because of a warning in the Asyncstorage library?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, gradle

I open the Android studio project in React Native and a warning appears to delete the buildToolsVersion Asyncstorage library

I deleted it and the warning disappeared and what the buildToolsVersion function is in the React Native Library

```
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
```

I want to know the use of buildToolsVersion and what it will do if I delete it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is okay to remove `buildToolsVersion`. The warning happens if you use the lower version than required minimum supported version for Android studio. For an example Android Gradle plugin 3.4.1 required minimum 28.0.3 buildToolsVersion. So If you remove that line it will use the default version of the build tools. Still, if you want to mention the buildToolsVersion, just keep a higher version of buildToolsVersion as your gradle plugin requires. Try `buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"` for your requirement.